# When window too smaller, the text goes away

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, positioning

I have floated a div to the right and put text in it. Whenever the window gets small the text just disappears completely. Am I positioning the text with a faulty technique or is there just something I am missing?

This is the css for the text I am trying to use:

```
.top_panel_text{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  min-width: 10px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Here is the rest of the code (you may have to expand the window to see the text at all):

http://jsfiddle.net/af5G6/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle at least, the text isn't disappearing, it's just getting displaced downwards. If you change the color of `p` in the CSs to blue you can see where it went. My guess is that it's a combination of the `float: right;` on the containing div `panel_2`, and the percentage margins on the classes `face_picture` and `top_panel_text`.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated the fiddle check it..

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/af5G6/1/)**

```
.top_panel_text{
  position: relative;
  float: right;
    color:black;
  min-width: 10px;

  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;

  margin-top: 10px;
}
p{
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

one thing to focus from your question:

If you want to contain the text within the div without getting hidden, you can just set `**overflow:scroll**` to the div..